# How to insert data frame value into Mongodb in R

Tags: json, r, mongodb

How to insert data frame value into Mongodb in R,

I'm using below code to insert but i'm getting error

`val` is my data frame.

My Insert Query is

```
 mongo1$insert(val)
```

But i'm getting Below error

> Error: No method asJSON S3 class: table

Comment: Pls include which library you are using

Comment: @vaettchen,sorry for delay,i'm using mongolite library